# Database error:No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it using EC2 + Linux + XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, wamp, lamp

I've got an EC2 instance running with a Linux server, and on it I've installed XAMPP. 
I have a chrome extension which needs to be able to connect to the DB created through phpMyAdmin, but when trying to connect I get the following error: Database error:No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

How can I allow an external server access to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Did you give [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en) a try?  It's unfortunate, but the only way I was able to find a chrome extension to allow CORS was with this extension.

Hope this helps.